# How do you search by Id?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm sure this is a silly question, but...

given the following Index

```
public class RandomIndex {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

How does one search by Id?

I can search by name just fine using NEST, but for some reason the ability to search by Id eludes me.  I'm guessing it's because it's a structured field?

Below is the SearchRequest I'm using.  Note that I can successfully query by name, just not by Id.

Note that this is in a function where I'm passing in the fieldName and the searchTerm to look for.

```
return new Nest.SearchRequest {
    From = offset,
    Size = 50,

    Query = new Nest.SimpleQueryStringQuery() {
      Query = $"\"{search}\"",
      Fields = new Nest.Field[] { fieldName }
    }
};
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on the `Id` field is the same as searching on any other field; with an `Id` field, it probably should be mapped as a [`keyword` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), in which case a [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on the field would work.

**But**, since NEST infers the [`_id` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) from an `Id` property on a POCO mapped to an Elasticsearch type and `_id` are unique for a type in an index, there would only ever be one match for the `Id` for a given type in a given index. Rather than searching against the `Id`, you can simply use the [GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html) to the get the document for the given id in an index. If you needed to search for the id across different indices and types, then the `term` query is what you're after.

Comment: I'm obviously new to ElasticSearch and so I'm trying to wrap my head around everything, including the underlying Lucene bits.  The GET API you mentioned seems perfect, but the issue is that I'm unsure how this maps to the .net NEST stuff.  I understand I can simply do a curl or manually put the requests together myself.  Do you have some guidance on this?  I've been finding this issue a lot, where the "low level" documentation explains how to do something, but I'm unsure how that maps back to the actual .Net API calls.  It's probably obvious, but I'm experiencing information overload atm.

Comment: `client.Get<MyDocument>()` or the async variant is what you're after. The method name on the client will align with the API name